# Too many levels of symbolic links after installing aws cli on Mac High Sierra

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, symlink

I am on Mac OS 10.13.2 High Sierra and trying to install aws cli following instructions here:  [aws cli instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html)

after installation, when I try to check it with `aws --version`, I get an error:

`-bash: /usr/local/bin/aws: /usr/local/aws/bin/python: bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links`

so I `cd` to `/usr/local/bin/` and `gedit aws` and see this:

```
#!/usr/local/aws/bin/python
# Copyright 2012 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.

# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"). You
# may not use this file except in compliance with the License. A copy of
# the License is located at

#     http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0/

# or in the "license" file accompanying this file. This file is
# distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF
# ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
# language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
import sys
import os

if os.environ.get('LC_CTYPE', '') == 'UTF-8':
    os.environ['LC_CTYPE'] = 'en_US.UTF-8'
import awscli.clidriver


def main():
    return awscli.clidriver.main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Then I try `gedit /usr/local/aws/bin/python` and get an error on `gedit` saying:

[image: screenshot error]

I am new to Mac, Unix and AWS so although I looked through other answers, it is difficult to apply them to my situation.  Please advise as to what I need to delete as I am guessing there is a circular reference or too many symbolic links but just not sure where to start digging.

Comment: You can do a `ls -l /usr/local/aws/bin/python` to see if the entry at that location is a symlink, and if so, what it is pointing to (and then run another `ls -l [...]` command on whatever it is pointing to, and so on, until you come to the end of the symlink-chain, or find that you've completed a cycle.  That won't fix the problem, of course, but at least you'd have an understanding of what the cycle looks like, which might help you figure out what a reasonable fix might be.

Comment: Hi there I read something about a circular reference and needing to put an absolute path to clear things up which it did, ie. my colleague helped me so I will post a solution shortly.  Thanks for patience.  I think we did what you advised though @JeremyFriesner